# How to place a sign with text using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a shop with items that get increasingly more expensive,

My problem is: How do I show the new price? This will be on a sign that I place, not in chat. Does anyone know how to place a sign with text using commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s pretty simple:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ oak_sign{Text1:'{"text":"Your Text Here"}'}
```

This creates a sign with "Your Text Here" on line 1. For other lines of the sign replace Text1 with Text2, Text3, or Text4. I recommend [McStacker](https://mcstacker.net) for even greater customization like colors or styles. It also supports other commands like `/summon` or `/give`.

Comment: how do i close this question?

Comment: @anomanous Mark an answer as accepted

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @anomanous There should be a gray checkmark underneath the answer’s vote buttons.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 My bad, missed a couple of quotes. I’ve updated the answer with the correct, tested command